# AMPScript for loop and SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

As the subject says, I would like to use two line of SSJS code in a for loop like in the example:

```
VAR @listAddress, @nameChosen, @Counter, @i, @AddressRow, 
SET @listAddress = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Object__c', 'Id, Name', 
                                                  'Name', '=', @nameChosen)

IF @Counter > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 to @Counter DO
        SET @AddressRow = Row(@listAddress, @i)
        SET @fieldRetrieved = Field(@AddressRow, 'Field__c')
            <script language="javascript" runat="server">
                var str = Variable.getValue("@fieldRetrieved ");
                var obj = {field : str};
                listRecord.push(obj);
            </script>
      NEXT @i
 ENDIF
```

Is it possibile that I am getting an error because I can't mix AMPScript for loop and SSJS?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the core library and some AMPscript block tags.  You'll need that to execute the proprietary functions:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");
</script>
%%[

VAR @listAddress, @nameChosen, @Counter, @i, @AddressRow, 
SET @listAddress = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Object__c', 'Id, Name','Name', '=', @nameChosen)

IF @Counter > 0 THEN

    FOR @i = 1 to @Counter DO

        SET @AddressRow = Row(@listAddress, @i)
        SET @fieldRetrieved = Field(@AddressRow, 'Field__c')

        ]%%

        <script language="javascript" runat="server">

            try {

              var str = Variable.getValue("@fieldRetrieved ");
              var obj = {field : str};
              listRecord.push(obj);

            } catch (e) {

              Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));

            }
        </script>

        %%[

      NEXT @i

 ENDIF

]%%
```

**Reference**

- [**Server-Side JavaScript Syntax**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_syntaxGuide.htm)

Comment: I think you need to close the AMPScript block before opening the SSJS block. Then reopen the block once SSJS block is completed.  E.g. add `]%%` after `'Field__c')` and add `%%[` before `NEXT @i`.

Comment: Duh, you're right.  Updated.

Comment: As I commented earlier (and deleted because of a mirage), if i delete the script in the for loop the code works again, and I have no clue at this point

Comment: You could try a try/catch block to see if you can identify the exception. That's a bonus of using SSJS.

Comment: The problem is that if I remove the SSJS block (including %%[ and ]%%) the code works. The AMPScript is a part of else-branch that is not executed in a test of the page, but it still returns me 500 error if the SSJS is included, works if removed.

Comment: Even if I use only a Write("123");

Comment: I resolved looping in the SSJS rather than in the AMPScript. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the same issue, it does not seem to work with the standard AMPscript code block tags %%[]%% but when you change these to <script language="ampscript" runat="server"> instead it works. So in your case it would look like this:

```
    <script language="javascript" runat="server">
        Platform.Load("Core", "1");
    </script>
    <script language="ampscript" runat="server">
        VAR @listAddress, @nameChosen, @Counter, @i, @AddressRow,
        SET @listAddress = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Object__c', 'Id, Name', 'Name', '=', @nameChosen)

        IF @Counter > 0 THEN

        FOR @i = 1 to @Counter DO

        SET @AddressRow = Row(@listAddress, @i)
        SET @fieldRetrieved = Field(@AddressRow, 'Field__c')
    </script>

    <script language="javascript" runat="server">
        try {

            var str = Variable.getValue("@fieldRetrieved ");
            var obj = {
                field: str
            };
            listRecord.push(obj);

        } catch (e) {

            Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));

        }
    </script>

    <script language="ampscript" runat="server">
        NEXT @i

        ENDIF
    </script>
```