# HTTPPost2 does not work, but in Postman works the Post

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I tried a simple HTTPPost2 to call a web service, but I got the 500 error.

```
%%[
var @payload, @postRequest, @response, @responseRows
set @payload = '{"KEY":"dataXml", "VALUE":"TEST"}'
set @postrequest = HTTPPost2("https://api.com","application/json;charset=UTF-8", @payload, false, @response, @responseRows)
]%%
status code: %%=v(@postrequest)=%%
<br><be>
response: %%=v(@response)=%%
<br><be>
responseRows: %%=v(@responseRows)=%%
<br><be>
responseRowCount: %%=RowCount(@responseRows)=%%
```

When I tried in Postman, it works fine. What could be wrong?[image]

Comment: Please update your question to include details about the header values used in your Postman call.

Comment: also, wrap your ampscript in an SSJS try/catch to get something meaningful back instead of a blank 500 error.
 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/ampscript-for-loop-and-ssjs/240640#240640

Comment: @AdamSpriggs.. the only headers is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'... No content more